# Make a global variable from onchange event

Tags: javascript, php

How do I make a global variable from an onchange event so that every functions in my js page can use the value from the variable? Can anyone provide a working sample code.

`onchange="showTable()"` event from **main.php**:

```
<?php
    $linkID = @ mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Newpass123#") or die("Could not connect to MySQL server");
    @ mysql_select_db("seatmapping") or die("Could not select database");
    $dbname = "seatmapping";
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname where tables_in_seatmapping!='userauth'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $tableNames= array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $tableNames[] = $row[0];
    }

    echo '<select name="tables" id="tables" onchange="showTable(this.value)">'; 
    echo '<option class="placeholder" selected disabled>Layouts</option>';
    foreach ($tableNames as $name){
        echo '<option value="'. $name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

`onclick="showAvailable()"` event from **main.php** as well:

```
<div class="sliderContainer">

    <div id="slider">
        <a class="ui-slider-handle" href="#">Start</a>
        <a class="ui-slider-handle" href="#">End</a>
    </div>

    <p>
    <a id="timer"><span class="slider-time">10:00 AM</span> to <span class="slider-time2">12:00 PM</span></a>

    <a href="#" id="checkAvailable" onclick="showAvailable()">Avail</a>
    <a href="#" id="resetAvailable" onclick="resetAvailable()">Reset</a></p>

</div>
```

My functions in a .js page:

```
var tableName;

function showTable(tableName){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("showLayout").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      tableName = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?tableName="+tableName,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function showAvailable(){
  var startShift = $('#slider').slider("values", 0);
  var endShift = $('#slider').slider("values", 1);

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("showLayout").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?startShift="+startShift+"&endShift="+endShift+"&tableName="+tableName,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And here is a snippet of **seatmap.php**, it's too long but I use the $tableName for both showAvailable and showTable. I also use it for in the query:

```
<?php

$startSlider=intval($_GET['startShift']);
$endSlider=intval($_GET['endShift']);
$tableName = strval($_GET['tableName']);

$linkID = @ mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Newpass123#") or die("Could not connect to MySQL server");
@ mysql_select_db("seatmapping") or die("Could not select database");

/* Create and execute query. */
$query = "SELECT rowId,columnId,status,name,seatid,startShift,endShift from $tableName group by seatid order by rowId, columnId desc";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$prevRowId = null;
$seatColor = null;
$tableRow = false;

//echo $result;
echo $tableName;
```

What I want is how to make the value from onchange=showTable(this.value) a global variable so I can use it in the function showAvailable and pass it to a php page. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the variable before function `showTable()`, e.g. `var global_var;`, then assign the value in the `showTable()`, and then you can use it in the `showAvailable()`, but remember to check if its not empty.

**Edit:** Your .js should be like this now (you were overriding some variables):

```
var tableName;

function showTable(localTable){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("showLayout").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      tableName = localTable;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?tableName="+localTable,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function showAvailable(){
  var startShift = $('#slider').slider("values", 0);
  var endShift = $('#slider').slider("values", 1);

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      document.getElementById("showLayout").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?startShift="+startShift+"&endShift="+endShift+"&tableName="+tableName,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanls for your help. But I have a question? How should I assign the value from the onchange event inside the showTable() after declaring the global variable inside the showTable()? I hope my question is clear. Thnx.

Comment: What value do you want to assign? `xmlhttp.responseText` from the AJAX?

Comment: Yes. Im sorry Im just a beginner. Hope you'd still help me out. Thnx

Comment: You can add after the line `document.getElementById("showLayout").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` line `global_var = xmlhttp.responseText;` and thats it.

Comment: I tried this and echoed the variable in the php. It's working fine when I select from the <select> with onchange="showTable()". But when I included it the showAvailable() it echoes undefined. Any idea why and how?

Comment: Can you update the code what you have now in the main post? Will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a global variable by adding a variable to the window object and it becomes visible to all functions.

```
window.globalValue = "some value";
```

But this is not the best approach, we should keep the globals to the minimum. The best practice is -
  create a namespace in the global
  add the variable to that global namespace.

In this way you can keep your global clean and the code is more maintainable.

```
window.Namespace = {};
Namespace.varOnChange = "some value";
```

I suppose what you are looking for is -

```
var myNamespace = {};

function showTable(tableName){
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("showLayout").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        myNamespace.name = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","seatmap.php?tableName="+tableName,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: but what if the global variable is dynamic. How should I declare it? Because the value of the global variable is suppose to come from the onchange event in my php page.

Comment: "We"? @rez—with square bracket notation: `var obj={}; obj[expr] = whatever;` an expression can be used for the property name.

Comment: If you are expecting a response from the server side language, in your case its php, then you can get it in the callback function of the ajax request. In the callback function, which looks something like this - function callbackResponse(data){ myNamespace.sercverResponse = data;}. You can declare the namespace on top of the js file, either through var myNamespace = {};, or by using window object as I have used in the above answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this and echoed it in php. When I use it in the showTable() it is fine. But when  I use it in the showAvailable() it just echoes [object Object]. Any ideas why and how?